# HTML5 application cache issue

Tags: html, google-chrome, offlineapps

Chrome Version (type about:version into your omnibox): 24.0.1312.57 m
Operating System (Windows 7/8/Vista/XP, Mac, Linux, Android, iOS):Windows 7
Extensions (type Chrome:extensions into your omnibox):None/All disabled

I am having an issue using html5 application cache feature. I am loosing the contents of application and web sql as soon as close the window. If I am on the same everything works fine but when I close the window and type the url which should pick the file based on application cache does not work and everything is empty when I check through developer tools.

What could be the possible issue?

-sk

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the HTML5 localStorage. That is persistent even if you close the browser.

Also, make sure there aren't any headers stating "no-cache" etc.

Comment: I am using web sql but the real point is about the application cache which has to launch the default page when I am offline.  In my manifest file I have FALLBACK:
./Default.htm and caching the default.htm. This file is shown(It also states in the console the file is loaded from application cache.) when I shutdown my IIS and try to access the url but only when I have not closed the window.

Comment: CACHE MANIFEST
# version50
./Default.htm
FALLBACK:
./Default.htm I am excluding other files

Comment: what is it? I don't see any link

Comment: That url will not help much to resolve this issue. As I said everything works fine as expected as long as I don't close the window. When I close the window and come back the application cache is lost.